# Where is the IMEI located on a Motorola phone?

Tags: imei, motorola

I have two motorola phones - One that I fastboot erase all'd 'accidently' and lost £300, so I was wondering if I could just transfer the IMEI from one phone to another?

Comment: What Moto device? It varies... Inside back cover, silkscreened on bottom, on SIM tray, maybe more. In the newest models it isn't, it was determined that electronic was good enough.

Comment: Don't ever try doing that - isn't that even illegal in some regions?

Comment: @AndyYan Yes, in some countries it is... Although in most it would be OK to transfer the IMEI from one phone to another, provided when you're done only one device has that IMEI number, meaning you have to remove the IMEI from the "donor" device or destroy it.

Comment: Why not just find out the original IMEI of the phone you have and put it back on that device? Your carrier often has it in their online service portal, it's on the device, on the box, etc...

Comment: @acejavelin ...which, from the tone of OP I don't think he's willing to do. Also, I don't think anyone (well maybe other than service centers) could just "write" EFS stuff back, or else countless EFS wipe mistakes would be saved easily.

Comment: @AndyYan True, and actually transferring or writing an IMEI to a Moto device isn't easy, you have to have a complete PDS partition dump for an identical model, modify it by hand in HEX with the desired IMEI, then write the entire partition, so you need an identical model donor device and not many people are willing to give up that partition because it also clones the MAC, serial number, and other unique information (or so I have heard, I haven't done it personally)

Comment: Writing a new IMEI is near to impossible, if not impossible itself. If anyone can give me suggestions I can try to fix my phone, I would be very grateful thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not move one IMEI to another phone.  That number is a lot like MAC address of every device that we use now a days. In theory, and with the help of root. Yes you can change the IMEI. However, that is alot of work.

The IMEI is unique to each phone and is how the authorities can help locate missing phones or even in many cases missing persons.

As for where you might find it. Look in your battery bay. or on the covers. if you have any of the documentation or even the box still.. you can also locate them there.

Comment: I know exactly what my IMEI number is. I just don't have it in my phone, because I deleted it accidentally.

Comment: but what i am suggesting is... look for it on the phones physical shell. a lot of times that info is written on the label. just like the mac is.

Answer (score -1):

You can reset or change your IMEI number without rooting your android phone.

Just follow this tutorial -> http://crazytechtricks.com/change-imei-number-android-mobile-phone-without-rooting/

Note: But, The risk is yours. There may be anything gonna happen.

Comment: The method on the page seems to be only for MediaTek-based devices.